# Select subsets of elements, and wrap them in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a set of selected elements in jQuery:

```
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
```

I would like to wrap these elements into groups of five like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Is there an efficient/easy way to do this? I imagine it would look something like this:

```
$('.element').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
```

But with a selector that selects the elements in groups of five.

Thanks!

Comment: Lots of great answers here! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it a bit mote compact like this:

```
var elems = $('.element');
for(var i = 0; i <= elems.length; i+=5) {
  elems.slice(i, i+5).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
}
```

This results in the exact result you have in the question :)  You can make that `5` a variable and wrap the number of children you want, the remainder (in this case the last 2) will be wrapped in their own wrapper at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = [];
$('.element').each(function(index, element) {
    elements.push(element);
    if (index > 0 && index % 4 == 0) {
        $(elements).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
        elements.splice(0, elements.length);
    }
});
$(elements).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a selector to do the job you can make use of 2, `:gt()` (greater-than) and `:lt()` (less-than):

```
$(".element:gt(9):lt(15)").wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
$(".element:gt(4):lt(10)").wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
$(".element:lt(5)").wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
```

Just make sure you do it in reverse order :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.element:nth-child(5n-4)').each(function(i){
    $(this).nextUntil('.element:nth-child(6n+'+i+')').andSelf()
        .wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elems = $('.element');
for(var i = 0; i <= elems.length-1; i+=5) {
  elems.slice(i, i+5).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
}
```

(changing `elems.length` to `elems.length-1`)
Since arrays start at 0, elems.length would give you 12, but elems[12] is undefined;

I would recommend using the native `for` as it is much faster than `.each()`